# Java proxy example is creating stack overflow?

Tags: java, reflection

I am putting together some foils and example code on Java reflection.
Here is my naive example code for using proxies:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

interface MyInterface { void foo(); }

class Handler implements InvocationHandler {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Called for : " + proxy);
    System.out.println("Called with: " + method);
    return null;
    }
}

public class ProxyExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    MyInterface proxied = (MyInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(MyInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] { MyInterface.class }, handler);
    proxied.foo();
    }
}
```

Can you guess what will happen?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:422)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:113)
at xxx..Handler.invoke(ProxyExample.java:15)
```

When I comment out the first printout, I get:

```
Called with: public abstract void xxx.MyInterface.foo()
```

Any idea what is causing the recursion and stack overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.out.println("Called for : " + proxy);`

Will call the proxy's `toString()` method, invoking the Handler again, causing infinite recursion.

Comment: That was my first thought, too. So I added a custom "toString()" to Handler - and it doesn't help?!